# How to resolve TS2786 error when importing vue@3.2.0 in type declaration file?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, vue-router

When I import `vue@3.2.0` in type declaration file，I will get TS2786 error.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9I7ZK.png)

This is the minimal implementation [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-7uekte?file=src%2Frouter%2Findex.d.ts). Run `pnpm exec tsc --noEmit`, you will get the error.

This is weird and I don't know how to fix it.